# Swift Custom TableViewCell wont show labels

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell class called CurrentFilesCell with the setting code below

```
class CurrentFileCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var statusImage: UIImageView!


var currentContent: AircraftContent! {
    didSet{
        setStyles(Constants.appStyleSetting)

        nameLabel.text = currentContent.contentName
        dateLabel.text = currentContent.contentStatus

    }
}
```

Within my CurrentFilesViewController I simply set it within cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CurrentFileCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CurrentFileCell
    cell?.currentContent = content

    return cell!
}
```

I believe I also have everything linked correctly, as I have done something similar to this in other classes, both with cells and vc's.
My problem is that It does not load anything when run, there is no default text and no updated text after it should have been set. Here is an image showing the linkage

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPCF7.jpg

I'm really not sure what is going on and why this isn't working. I have tried deleting it and recreating but I must be missing something.

EDIT
Here is a picture of the debugger showing that the cell's currentContent is not empty. This is taken right before the return cell! is executed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbkFG.jpg

Comment: First, if the code is not crashing you must use the debugger to step through your code and check that the correct number of sections, the correct number of rows in a section and the correct content is returned. Secondly, try reloading the tableview to check that the info is correctly set and that this is just not an issue with the `UITableViewCell` lifecycle (i.e. the outlets of the cell may not be set in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`). Thirdly, edit your question to include all this information.

Comment: I added another image to show that it is not empty

Comment: OK. Add an image of the actual cell at runtime and use the view debugger to check the cell in case your constraints are wrong and have pushed the labels / images off-screen.

Comment: @John511 You could run the UI debugger and investigate where the labels are. Maybe you're missing constraints or the current constraints are not set properly. More info about UI debugging [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6)

Answer (score 0):

Did you register this cell in table view? If not than `dqueRqusableCellWithIdentifier` will return nil value...
You can register it using UITableView function "`registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier`:"

Comment: Not completely sure what you mean by this. Can you explain any more?

Comment: When you are creating custom cell, than you have two possibilities: 
1) prototype cell
2) using XIB file

Using second approach you need to register your cell in table view(so your table view know from where to take UI for such cell). Does it make sense now? If not  i can give more deep explanation.

Comment: I am just using a prototype cell so not sure if that applies.

Comment: Yes, if you are using Prototype cell, than it's automatically registered. 
Than there is needed more brief debug as your code looks fine.

Comment: You can check if in the time when you are filling content cell is not nil or cells labels is not nil. That is possible situations.

Answer (score 0):

In the storyboard, you must define subclass of the prototype table cell.

And then, you must define identifier of the prototype table cell as "CurrentFileCell".

Then you will show the content of the table when the app will be run.